# QML resolution independent application

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml, qtquick2

Is it possible to use some resolution independent measurement unit in Qt/QML?

I would like to make the size of the text, buttons, margins,  decorative rectangles... the equal in desktop (retina and non-retina), android (dpi, xspi...) and iOS (retina and non-retina)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can access all your parent components in an element you can base all your widths/heights off the parent heights. e.g.

```
Rectangle
{
  width: parent.width / 2
  anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```